# Is there a way to enable/disable a certain key from softkeyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I just wanted to enable and disable return key on some events..Is there a way to disable/enable the return key?

Comment: What if I tell you I use SwiftKey? Or any other custom soft keyboard? How would you handle these?

Comment: Might be possible on individual inputs, but probably not app-wide